# Is Microsoft Build tools allowed to be redistributed?

Tags: msbuild, wix

Can I redistribute Microsoft Build Tools in a installer like is allowed with .net frameworks? I know from a technical standpoint it is possible. I am more curious from a legal standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license to use the build tools on your(!) devices and for use within the organization is actually part of the Visual Studio licence.

Its [license terms](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553512/) read:

> Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates) licenses this supplement to you. Refer to your license terms for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 software (the “software”) as those terms apply to your use of this supplement. **You may use a copy of this supplement with each validly licensed copy of the software. You may not use the supplement if you do not have a license for the software.**

The specific usage of the build tools (installing on build machines) is part of the Visual Studio license (see [this Visual Studio 2017 license](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt687465/))

So if you want to have some build tooling distributed with your software and not require users to have a Visual Studio license, consider using JetBrain's MSBuild distribution. See their [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/13/introducing-jetbrains-redistributable-msbuild/) on it.