# Cannot compile template C++/CLI (.NET Core 3.1) project via dotnet build command

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

1. Install latest stable **Visual Studio 2019 16.4.2** (check **.NET Core Development** and **Desktop development with C++** workloads, also make sure that **C++/CLI support** component in checked).
2. Create new project with CLR Class Library (.NET Core)
   template (or CLR Empty Project (.NET Core) if you like).
3. Compilation via **dotnet build** command will fail (**dotnet build CLRNetCoreTest.sln
       /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86**):
   [image]

Compilation via **msbuild** command is successfull (**"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" CLRNetCoreTest.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86**).

And that is very strange - I supposed **dotnet** to be a wrapper built on the top of **msbuild**..

Sample project is **[attached](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/113600-clrnetcoretest.zip)** (run **Build.bat** for compilation).

Comment: It's actually a C++ project, dotnet build can't work for C++ projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add more details:

> And that is very strange - I supposed dotnet to be a wrapper built on
>   the top of msbuild.

Agree with **Martin**, `dotnet build` for now doesn't support building C++ project, cause dotnet cli doesn't know where to find the necessary C++ `xx.targets` and `xx.props`.

Your project is a C++/CLR project(xx.vcxproj) whose target framework is `.net core`, it has big difference with actual `.net core` projects(xx.csproj or xx.vbproj), the `xx.vcxproj` imports many C++ specific files which is not included in `.net core sdk`.

For example: Go `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\xxx` you can find many msbuild targets and props files there, but you can't find **Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props** file. This file comes from C++ workload instead of .net core SDK.

So though `dotnet build` uses msbuild to build project, it actually doesn't use the same msbuild.exe from VS folder(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\xxx\xxx\MSBuild\1xxx\Bin\MSBuild.exe`). And only the msbuild.exe from VS IDE or MSBuild build tools package can be used to build this project.

**In addition:**

If your final goal is to build the project in remote server, maybe you're looking for Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` package.(Free if you've gotten corresponding lisense, more details see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08d62115-0b51-484f-afda-229989be9263/license-for-visual-c-2017-build-tools)) It doesn't require VS IDE to be installed. (Download link [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/))

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. BTW we are already using `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` on our server. But it is not **free**, it [requires](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08d62115-0b51-484f-afda-229989be9263/license-for-visual-c-2017-build-tools) the same [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256313/is-microsoft-build-tools-allowed-to-be-redistributed) as Visual Studio

Comment: Hmmm, if you've met the requirements of free VS2019 community version, since the build tool is a supplement of it, you can also use the free build tool, no need to install the full VS community 2019 version...

Comment: Our company is enterprise and doesn't meet requirements of free VS2019 community version.

Comment: `Free if you've gotten corresponding lisense` could be more suitable! Just update the answer with the useful info you shared, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ projects can only be built with the `msbuild.exe` shipped with Visual Studio as it relies on Visual Studio's C++ tooling.

The cross-platform `dotnet` command with its cross-platform MSBuild distribution does not have these tools and as such unable to compile C++ projects. The `dotnet` command does not use the visual studio version of MSBuild.

Comment: Thank you. You were first but **Lance Li-MSFT** provided more detailed answer.

Comment: Hi Martin, do you have experience with solution that has mixed projects, csproj and vcxproj? If I try dotnet build on solution level, vcxproj cannot build. While csproj projects can build... I am in process of converting .net4.8 to .net5.0 and this is one of things that I struggle with.