# How can I exclude vcxprojs from dotnet test?

Tags: c++, msbuild, .net-5

I have a solution of .NET 5 SDK-style csprojs that works with `dotnet build` and `dotnet test`. I'd like to add a C++ project to it (pure C++, not C++/CLI), which breaks these.

The error I get is

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

which is caused by `dotnet` not supporting C++. Fair enough. I can work around `dotnet build` by just using `msbuild` but what can I do for `dotnet test`? I don't care about testing the C++ project, just want to keep existing functionality working. If I could somehow make it exclude vcxprojs that would be great.

Comment: Judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730669/2552903), dotnet CLI doesn't support building C++. Apparently that is because the msbuild version shipped with .NET SDK and invoked by the dotnet CLI is not aware of certain `xx.targets` and `xx.props` files. Therefore you should install MSBuild Tools and invoke msbuild from there (something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\xxx\xxx\MSBuild\1xxx\Bin\MSBuild.exe`).